# Difference between Sha1WithRSA and Sha1WithRSAEncryption?

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, sha1, public-key-encryption

I've noticed these two algorithms that have different names, but functionally sound very similar. When I looked further, I've found out `Sha1WithRSA` is available across many Security Providers, but `Sha1WithRSAEncryption` is only available if I use the `BouncyCastle` Provider.

Example:
`JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1WithRSAEncryption").setProvider("BC")`

Is it replacable with 
`JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1WithRSA").setProvider("SunJSSE")` ?

Can someone throw some insight into this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you take a look at BouncyCastle source code you will notice that both [SHA1WITHRSAENCRYPTION](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/operator/DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.java#L46) and [SHA1WITHRSA](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/operator/DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.java#L47) indicate the same algorithm - 
RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 signature with SHA-1 hash algorithm which is also identified by OID [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/asn1/pkcs/PKCSObjectIdentifiers.java#L23).

Comment: Awesome, I almost came to the same conclusion when I was messing around with all the algorithms available with other providers.